# The setState is working only for some values and it does not make any sense

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, tailwind-css

```
const [colorTheme, setColorTheme] = useState("#8D9093");

const getColorTheme = (websiteName) => {
  const website = websiteData.find(
    (site) => site.name.toLowerCase() === websiteName.toLowerCase()
  );

  if (website) {
    console.log(website.colorTheme);
    setColorTheme(website.colorTheme);
  } else {
    console.log("Website not found");
    setColorTheme("#8D9093");
  }
};
```

I am fetching colorTheme from a JSON file.

```
    {
        "name": "YouTube",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=",
        "colorTheme": "#FF0000"
    },
```

And this is one of the examples of how I'm using colorTheme in tailwind

```
className={`h-fit w-fit px-2 rounded-xl bg-[${colorTheme}] shadow-[0_0_5px_${colorTheme},0_0_15px_${colorTheme}] text-white`}
```

The color changes only for the YouTube's colorTheme(#FF0000) and does not change for anything else. But I can that being set for every website in the console. How can it change of one and not for others.

[Its changing for Youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBkJK.png)
[And not for others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KCh9.png)

Comment: Does changing the setState to `setColorTheme(() => _whatever_);` make a difference?

Comment: Is the problem that *state* isn't updating, or is the problem that the styling isn't doing what you expect?  The pictures linked to suggest that *state* is working just fine.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David The state is changing as you can see in the console. But it works only for one value (#FF0000). but doesn't for other values. When I set state to those other values directly (eg setState(#F72617)), it works. So there is not problem with the styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Consider using the `style` attribute instead:

```
<div
  className="h-fit w-fit px-2 rounded-xl text-white"
  style={{
    backgroundColor: colorTheme,
    boxShadow: `0 0 5px ${colorTheme}, 0 0 15px ${colorTheme}`,
  }}
>
```